# how to invoke safari's search method by send hot key from javascript

Tags: javascript, safari

In my Mac OS, I use Safari and Firefox, and I am a Vimer. I like Vim operation, I use Firefox because of the Vimperator, but I use Safari because of its power.

Vimari is the best Vim extension in Safari, but I can not use hotkey <kbd>/</kbd> to invoke the Safari search method. I have the soft keyboard maestro. I use it to map the hotkey, but I can not input the char `/` in address bar, because the mapping applies to it as well，so sometimes it is not useful.

**Can anyone show me how to use JavaScript when I press <kbd>/</kbd> to send the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> hotkey to Safari and invoke the search method when I'm browsing?**